# Laplace Transform of: $\cos(4t) * \sin(3t)$

Tags: laplace-transform

I am new to Laplace Transform so Can anyone please solve this question ?
$$
\mathcal{L}\left[ \cos( 4t ) * \sin( 3t )\right]
$$

Comment: Convulsion or muliply?

Comment: @dmtri Convolution surely, but that's an excellent typo!

Comment: I am new to this website and Laplace Transform too

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**HINT**

One of the famous properties of the Laplace transform is that it converts convolution into multiplication, so one step may be
$$
\mathcal{L}\left[ \cos( 4t ) * \sin( 3t )\right]
 = \mathcal{L}\left[ \cos( 4t )\right]
   \cdot \mathcal{L}\left[ \sin( 3t )\right]
$$

Can you take it from here?

Comment: Unfortunately no

Comment: @OmarAhmed please consider reading [Wikipedia on Laplace Transform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laplace_transform) and then doing some work of your own. Post it here and I am happy to guide you further.

Comment: Alright.. Thanks Alot :)

Answer (score 0):

In Mathematica you would write

```
Clear[t, s, m];
Integrate[Cos[4*t]*Sin[3*t]*Exp[-s*t], {t, 0, Infinity}]
```

which gives the output:

ConditionalExpression[(3 (-7 + s^2))/(49 + 50 s^2 + s^4), Re[s] > 0]

which is the same as:

```
LaplaceTransform[Cos[4*t]*Sin[3*t], t, s]
```

which gives the output:

(3 (-7 + s^2))/(49 + 50 s^2 + s^4)

Comment: Just a tip - in Mathematica if you highlight an expression and right-click, there is an option in the context menu to "copy as" LaTeX.